# What is causing the 'string index out of range' error when adding a new column to a pandas dataframe using iteration?

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I have a dataframe with 51108 rows called 'df' and I want to add a new column called 'metric' based on the values of other column (called 'type') that appear on the following row. When I try to execute the code below, the following issue is raised: 'string index out of range'

```
pass_pre_shot = []
n = 0

if n < 56107:
  for value in compact['type']:
    if value[n+1] == 'Shot':
      pass_pre_shot.append(1)
    elif value[n+1] == 'Pass':
      pass_pre_shot.append(0)
    else:
      pass
    n = n+1
```

I want the new column to have the values 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

Because value='Shot' (or 'Pass'), so value[4] doesn't exist...

Try this instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# create a df that looks like yours
type_list = [random.choice(['Shot', 'Pass']) for _ in range(51108)]
df = pd.DataFrame(type_list, columns=['type'])

# add a new column that holds the next value of 'type'
df['next type'] = df.type.shift(-1)

# create a third column by applying a lambda function that checks if 
# type == 'Pass' and next_type == 'Shot'
df['pass_pre_shot'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if (x['type'] == 'Pass' and x['next type'] == 'Shot') else 0, axis=1)
```